# Auto unmount time machine drive on sleep

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, sleep-wake

I keep a drive attached to my MacBook for Time Machine backups when I'm at my desk. I also regularly work from places other than my desk. Most of the time, if I close the laptop lid I intend to leave my desk, so I need to unmount the drive. Is there any way to automate this, so that the OS automatically unmounts the drive before sleep? I figure my options are

1. Just be a bad computer user and unplug the drive. (yikes)
2. Manually remember to unmount the drive… This takes 15-20 seconds altogether, and I'll forget at least some of the time.
3. Figure out how to make it automatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ioreg` to test if your lid is closed or open:

```
ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep AppleClamshellState
```

No= Lid is open
Yes= Lid is closed

You can use `diskutil unmount /dev/<mydisk>` to unmount the TimeCapsule.
Use `diskutil list` to find the disk location of the TimeCapsule.

Using if statements you can automate the job:

```
if [[ $(ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep AppleClamshellState | grep Yes) ]]; then echo Lid Closed; diskutil unmount /dev/<mydisk>; fi
```

You can use launchd to set up a automated job that is repeated for example every second (see how to here: http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs)